# Dominated Convergence Theorem and Holomorphic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

This is exercise 133Xc in Fremlin Volume 1:

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open. Let $f:X\times G\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function and suppose that the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ of $f$ with respect to the second variable exists for all $x\in X$, $z\in G$. Suppose also that $(i)$ $F(z)=\int f(x,z) dx$ exists for every $z\in G$ and $(ii)$ there is an integrable function $g$ such that $\lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (x,z) \rvert \leq g(x)$ for every $x\in X$, $z\in G$. Show that the derivative $F'$ of $F$ exists everywhere in $G$, and $F'(z)=\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (x,z) dx$ for every $z\in G$. (*Hint:* you will need to check that $\lvert f(x,z)-f(x,w) \rvert \leq \lvert z-w \rvert g(x)$ whenever $x\in X, z\in G$ and $w$ is close to $z$.)

My attempt:

Let $w\in G$ and let $(w_n)$ be a sequence in $G\setminus\{w\}$ converging to $w$. For each $n$ we have

$$\frac{F(w_n)-F(w)}{w_n-w}=\int \frac{f(x,w_n)-f(x,w)}{w_n-w} dx$$ Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined by

$$f_n(x)=\frac{f(x,w_n)-f(x,w)}{w_n-w}$$ for all $n$ and all $x\in X$. Suppose I can show that $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x\in X$. Then, since $f_n(x)\to \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,w)$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $x\in X$, I can invoke the DCT (complex version) to deduce that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(w_n)-F(w)}{w_n-w}= \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,w) dx$$

Since $(w_n)$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

My problem is how to show the inequality $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq g(x)$. In the real case we can invoke the MVT to obtain this inequality but in the complex case I don't know how to proceed. It is supposed to be a basic exercise but somehow I don't have the right tool.

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I posted a solution attempt below based on DavidC.Ulrich's comments. But I have the problem that $\alpha_z$ is a function of $z$ and I can't prove that this function is differentiable.

Comment: The fact that $|f_n|\le g$ follows from the Mean Value Theorem and the hypothesis on $\partial f/\partial w$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was not aware of the existence of a MVT for complex functions! How can I show this?

Comment: MVT is false for complex-valued functions, but all the important corollaries still hold. Here for example, fix $x$, choose $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha f(x)=|f(x)|\ge0$, and let $u$ be the real part of $\alpha f$; then MVT shows that $u(x)\le g(x)$, hence $|f(x)|\le g(x)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see but here the function also has a complex domain. Hence the real part of $f$ is a real-valued function with complex domain.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I would be very grateful if you could spell out the details.

Comment: Which details??

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If I understand correctly you suggest to apply the MVT to the function $z \mapsto \alpha f(x,z)$ defined for all $z \in G$. But the MVT theorem that I know is for differentiable functions $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. with interval domain $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Choose $r>0$ so $\overline{B(w,r)}\subset G$. Assume wlog that $|w-w_n|<r$. Then the line seqment $[w,w_n]$ lies in $K$;  the application of MVT is to the restriction to this seqment.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  What is $K$? By $\bar{B(w,r)}$ do you mean the closure of the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $w$?

Comment: I meant to say $K=\overline{B(w,r)}$, sorry.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you please take a look at the solution that I posted? I have a problem with the fact that $\alpha_z$ is actually a function of $z$ and I can't show that it is differentiable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Advanced calculus" details, on request:

> > **Lemma.** Suppose $G\subset \Bbb C$ is open, $f:G\to\Bbb C$ is complex-differentiable, and $|f'(z)|\le c$ for all $z$. If the segment $[z,w]$ lies in $G$ then $|f(z)-f(w)|\le c|z-w|$.

Proof: **Fix** $z,w$ with $[z,w]\subset G$. Choose $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with $|\alpha|=1$ and $$|f(z)-f(w)|=\alpha(f(z)-f(w).$$Define $$u=\Re(\alpha f)$$and define $\phi:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by $$\phi(t)=u(tw+(1-t)z).$$Then MVT shows there exists $s\in[0,1]$ with $$\begin{aligned}|f(w)-f(z)|&=u(1)-u(0)=u'(s)\\&=\Re\alpha(w-z)f'(sw+(1-s)z)\\&\le|(w-z)f'(sw+(1-s)z)|\le c|z-w|.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for these details. Two questions : 1) How do you know that $Re(\alpha f)$ is differentiable? I know $\alpha f$ is complex differentiable by assumption but why is the real part also differentiable? Also it seems like an alpha is missing in the last part. 2) Why can you "add" an absolute value in the last equality?

Comment: (1) It's clear from the definitions that if $f$ is complex-differentiable and $\phi=\Re f$ then $\phi$ has partial derivatives. (2): I revised that last display - if it's not clearer now ask again.

Comment: @David.C.Ullrich I looked carefully but I don't see any revision to your post.

Comment: Jest to label things, say the last display is $A=B=C=D=E\le F$. We know $D=A$. Hence $D\ge0$, so $D=|D|=E$.

Comment: Ahh I see! Regarding your second comment I believe we need $Re(\alpha f)$ to be differentiable, and the fact that partial derivatives exist doesn't implies differentiability. When you say $Re(\alpha f)$ is differentiable do you mean real ($\mathbb{R}^2$) differentiable or complex differentiable?

Comment: "When you say Re(αf) is differentiable do you mean real or complex differentiable?" I don't believe I ever said it was differentiable. I was about to say "real differentiable" and then decided to write "has partial derivatives" instead. In fact the real part of a holomorphic function is $C^\infty$, hence we can certainly apply the chain rule.

Comment: Ok so we need that $Re(\alpha f)$ is complex differentiable to apply the chain rule in this case correct? Neither real differentiability or the existence of partial derivatives is sufficient ? How can I show complex differentiability ?

Comment: No, $\Re\alpha f$ is certainly not complex-differentiable! That's obvious, since it's real-valued and non-constant. This is all sounding like maybe you simply don't have the required background - this will all make more sense if you (i) learn a little complex variables (in particular the connection between analytic functions and harmonic functions, (ii) a little several-real-variable calculus, in particular the chain rule.

Comment: Note the absence of hypotheses regarding complex differentiability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: A function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable at $z_0=x_0+ i y_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ iff $Re(f),Im(f):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ are both differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. In this case $\frac{\partial Re(f(x,y)) }{\partial x}=Re f'(z_0)$ and $\frac{\partial Re(f(x,y)) }{\partial y}=- Im f'(z_0)$.

Comment: If $x(t),y(t)$ are both real differentiable functions and $f(x,y)$ is real differentiable then the chain rule for total derivatives says that  $f(x(t),y(t))$ is differentiable and $\frac{d f}{dt}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial x} x'(t) + \frac{\partial f }{\partial y} y'(t)$.

Comment: Applying this to the function $u(t)$ we get $u'(t)=Re(\alpha f')(Re (w) -Re (z))-Im(\alpha f')(Im (w) -Im (z))= Re \big [ (w-z)\alpha f'\big ]$. Hence I think there is $Re$ and $\alpha$ missing after the 3rd equality. Also $t$ should be $z$.

Comment: (I inserted the missing $\Re$ and $\alpha$ the other day - must have missed the SaveChanges or something...)

Comment: Right. We also need the fact that $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are real differentiable, which is what I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed you'd said "real differentiable" and deleted that comment. Too late alas...

Comment: Another proof (assuming $f'$ is integrable) is $|f(z)-f(w)|=\left|\int_{\gamma}f'(z)dz\right|\le \int_{\gamma}|f'(z)|dz\le c|z-w|$. The nice thing about it is that is allows to generalize the statement to a set that does not contain the segment $z-w$.

Comment: @Caffeine (Note there are too many $z$'s in your notation...) The advantage to a proof by MVT is it often works in other situations where there is no fundamental theorem of calculus available... of course here that's no problem since a holomorphic function is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Following DavidC.Ulrich's advice here is my solution.

Since $w\in G$ and $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open, there exist $r>0$ such that $B(w,r)\subset G$, where $B(w,r)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $w$. Since $w_n\to w$, we may assume WLOG that $(w_n)\subset B(w,r)$, for otherwise we can start the sequence at a larger $n$ without affecting the limit.

Fix $x\in X$ and $n$. For each $z \in G$ there exist a complex number $\alpha_z$ such that $$\alpha_z f(x,z)=\lvert f(x,z) \rvert $$

Indeed $\alpha_z$ can be taken to be $e^{-i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is an argument of the complex number $f(x,z)$. Note that the RHS of the equality shows that $\alpha_z f(x,z)$ is real for all $z \in G$.

Because the line $\{(1-t)w_n+tw : t\in[0,1]\}$ lies in $G$, we can define the function $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$h(t)=\alpha_z f(x,(1-t)w_n+tw)$$

Moreover, because $\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial z}$ exists for all $z \in G$ and $\frac{\partial (1-t)w_n+tw }{\partial t} =w-w_n$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, the chain rule implies that $h$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ with

$$h'(t)=\alpha_z \frac{\partial f(x,(1-t)w_n+tw)}{\partial z} (w-w_n)$$

Now, we can apply the MVT to $h$ to obtain obtain $c \in (0,1)$ such that

$$ h(1)-h(0)=h'(c)$$

Translating back in terms of $f$ we get

$$ \alpha_z f(x,w)-\alpha_z f(x,w_n) = \alpha_z\frac{\partial f(x,(1-c)w_n+cw)}{\partial z} (w-w_n) $$

Taking absolute values on both sides, cancelling out $\lvert \alpha_z \rvert$ and dividing by $\lvert w-w_n \rvert$ we get

$$ \lvert f_n(x) \rvert = \Bigg \lvert \frac{ f(x,w)- f(x,w_n) }{ w-w_n } \Bigg \rvert = \Bigg \lvert \frac{\partial f(x,(1-c)w_n+cw)}{\partial z} \Bigg \rvert \leq g(x)$$

Since $x\in X$ and $n$ were arbitrary we are done.

PROBLEM : I DIDN'T TAKE INTO ACCOUNT THE FACT THAT $\alpha_z$ IS A FUNCTION of $z$!